# TCP ZeroWindow Issue C#

Tags: c#, tcp, client, tcpclient, tcpserver

i have been writing a file server/client application in c# and it appeared to be working but then i realized the the stream was not being advanced and the client kept failing to receive from the server. so i checked wireshark and saw that my client was emitting TCPZeroWindow flagged packets. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Client :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
namespace PortalClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static string s1;
        static byte[] data03;
        static int int02;
        static string str01;
        static int length;
        static IPEndPoint ipe01;
        static TcpClient tcp01;
        static FileStream s01;
        static string ip01;
        static string port01;
        static string path01;
        static byte[] data01;
        static byte[] data02;
        static byte[] data04;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            while (true)
            {
            label1:
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string version = "V:1.1.4";
                        Console.Title = (" Portal Client " + version);
                        ConsoleColor ccolor1 = new ConsoleColor();
                        ccolor1 = Console.ForegroundColor;
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("         PORTAL CLIENT " + version);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ccolor1;
                        data01 = new byte[20];
                        data03 = new byte[100];
                        data04 = new byte[100];
                        Console.Write(" Enter IPv4 address of server : ");
                        ip01 = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write(" Enter port to connect on : ");
                        port01 = Console.ReadLine();
                        ipe01 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip01), Convert.ToInt32(port01));
                        tcp01 = new TcpClient();
                        tcp01.ReceiveTimeout = 2500;
                        tcp01.NoDelay = true;
                        Console.WriteLine(" Connecting...");
                        tcp01.Connect(ipe01);
                        Console.WriteLine(" Done.");
                        tcp01.Client.Receive(data04, SocketFlags.None);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                        Console.WriteLine(" Server message : " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data04));
                        tcp01.Client.Receive(data03, SocketFlags.None);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                        Console.WriteLine(" File on server : " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data03));
                        tcp01.Client.Receive(data01, SocketFlags.None);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                        str01 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data01);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine(" file size : " + str01);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.Write(" Enter the number you see above : ");
                        length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.Write(" Save file as : ");
                        path01 = Console.ReadLine();
                        for (int i = 1; i <= 9000; i++)
                        {
                            if (length % i == 0) { int02 = i; }
                        }
                        if (length < 9000) { int02 = length; }
                        int int03 = length / int02;
                        s01 = File.OpenWrite(@path01);
                        Console.WriteLine(" Receiving file from " + tcp01.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + "...");
                        tcp01.Client.Send(new byte[1], SocketFlags.None);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        for (int i = 0; i <= int03; i++)
                        {
                            bool bool1 = false;
                            data02 = new byte[int02];
                            int n = tcp01.Client.Receive(data02, 0, int02, SocketFlags.None);
                            while (n < int02)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(" Entered Loop ");
                                int int04 = int02 - n;
                                tcp01.Client.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("2"), 0, 1, SocketFlags.None);
                                int int05 = 0;
                                byte[] data05 = new byte[int04];
                                if (int04 >= 1 && int04 <= 9) { s1 = int04 + "xxx"; }
                                if (int04 >= 10 && int04 <= 99) { s1 = int04 + "xx"; }
                                if (int04 >= 100 && int04 <= 999) { s1 = int04 + "x"; }
                                if (int04 >= 1000 && int04 <= 9000) { s1 = int04.ToString(); }
                                tcp01.Client.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s1), 0, 4, SocketFlags.None);
                                int05 = tcp01.Client.Receive(data05, 0, int04, SocketFlags.None);
                                n = n + int05;
                                s01.Write(data05, 0, int05);
                                bool1 = true;
                            }
                            if (bool1 == false)
                            {
                                s01.Write(data02, 0, int02);
                                tcp01.Client.Send(new byte[1], 0, 1, SocketFlags.None);
                            }
                        }
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        s01.Close();
                        Console.WriteLine(" Received all data.");
                        Console.WriteLine(" Press enter to disconnect...");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        tcp01.Client.Send(new byte[1], SocketFlags.None);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        Console.WriteLine(" Disconnecting...");
                        tcp01.Close();
                        Console.WriteLine(" Done.");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(" Error! : " + e.Message.ToString() + " - " + e.Data.ToString() + " - " + e.TargetSite.ToString()); if (!(tcp01 == null)) { tcp01.Close(); } if (!(s01 == null)) { s01.Close(); goto label1; }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Server :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
namespace PortalServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static long length;
        static int int03;
        static int int02;
        static TcpListener tcp01;
        static TcpClient tcp02;
        static FileStream s01;
        static byte[] data01;
        static byte[] data03;
        static byte[] data04;
        static byte[] data05;
        static string str01;
        static string str02;
        static IPEndPoint ipe01;
        static string port01;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
            label1:
                try
                {
                    string version = "V:1.1.4";
                    Console.Title = (" Portal Server " + version);
                    ConsoleColor ccolor1 = new ConsoleColor();
                    ccolor1 = Console.ForegroundColor;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("         PORTAL SERVER " + version);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ccolor1;
                    Console.Write(" Enter port for connecting clients : ");
                    port01 = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write(" Enter path of file to send : ");
                    str01 = Console.ReadLine();
                    ipe01 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Convert.ToInt32(port01));
                    tcp01 = new TcpListener(ipe01);
                    Console.Write(" Enter server message : ");
                    str02 = Console.ReadLine();
                    s01 = File.OpenRead(@str01);
                    length = s01.Length;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 9000; i++)
                    {
                        if (length % i == 0) { int02 = i; } 
                    }
                    if (length < 9000) { int02 = (int)length;}

                    int03 = (int)length / int02;
                    tcp01.Start();
                    Console.WriteLine(" Server started. Waiting for clients...");
                    tcp02 = tcp01.AcceptTcpClient();
                    tcp02.Client.NoDelay = true;
                    Console.WriteLine(" Client " + tcp02.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + " connected.");
                    data05 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str02);
                    tcp02.Client.Send(data05, SocketFlags.None);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    data04 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str01);
                    tcp02.Client.Send(data04, SocketFlags.None);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    data03 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(length.ToString());
                    tcp02.Client.Send(data03, SocketFlags.None);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Waiting for response...");
                    tcp02.Client.Receive(new byte[1], SocketFlags.None);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Received response...");
                    Console.WriteLine(" Sending file to " + tcp02.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + "...");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                    for (int i = 0; i <= int03;i++ )
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30);
                        data01 = new byte[int02];
                        s01.Read(data01, 0, data01.Length);
                        int n = tcp02.Client.Send(data01, 0 ,data01.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                        if (n != int02) { throw new Exception("unable to write bytes, insufficient memory."); }
                        byte[] data07 = new byte[1];
                        while (true)
                        {
                            tcp02.Client.Receive(data07,0,1,SocketFlags.None);
                            if (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data07) == "2") 
                            {
                                byte[] data06 = new byte[4];
                                int b = tcp02.Client.Receive(data06, 0, 4, SocketFlags.None);
                                if (b != 4) { throw new Exception("ex1"); }
                                string s1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data06);
                                s1 = s1.Replace("x", "");
                                int int05 = Convert.ToInt32(s1);
                                int int06 = int02 - int05;
                                byte[] data08 = new byte[int05];
                                Buffer.BlockCopy(data01, int06, data08, 0, int05);
                                tcp02.Client.Send(data08, 0, data08.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    s01.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine(" All data sent.");
                    Console.WriteLine(" Waiting for terminate message...");
                    tcp02.Client.Receive(new byte[1], SocketFlags.None);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Received terminate message.");
                    tcp02.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine(" Stopping client and server.");
                    tcp01.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine(" Done. Restarting.");

                }

                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Error! : " + e.Message.ToString() + " - " + e.Data.ToString() + " - " + e.TargetSite.ToString());
                    if (!(tcp02 == null)) { tcp02.Close(); }
                    if (!(tcp01 == null)) { tcp01.Stop(); goto label1; }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used separate threads for the heavy lifting send / receive methods, increased buffer size, increased time between sends, made sure fragmentation was on. works like a charm now.

client :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace PortalClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static int partloop;
        static bool bool1;
        static byte[] data05;
        static int int03;
        static int int04;
        static int int05;
        static int numbytesreceived;
        static BackgroundWorker bw1;
        static int bytestoreceive;
        static string s1;
        static byte[] data03;
        static int int02;
        static string str01;
        static int length;
        static IPEndPoint ipe01;
        static TcpClient tcp01;
        static FileStream s01;
        static string ip01;
        static string port01;
        static string path01;
        static byte[] data01;
        static byte[] data02;
        static byte[] data04;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            newvoid();
        }
        static void newvoid()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WindowWidth = 95;
                    string version = "V:1.1.4";
                    Console.Title = (" Portal Client " + version);
                    ConsoleColor ccolor1 = new ConsoleColor();
                    ccolor1 = Console.ForegroundColor;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(@"
 __________              __         .__    _________ .__  .__               __   
 \______   \____________/  |______  |  |   \_   ___ \|  | |__| ____   _____/  |_ 
  |     ___/  _ \_  __ \   __\__  \ |  |   /    \  \/|  | |  |/ __ \ /    \   __\
  |    |  (  <_> )  | \/|  |  / __ \|  |__ \     \___|  |_|  \  ___/|   |  \  |  
  |____|   \____/|__|   |__| (____  /____/  \______  /____/__|\___  >___|  /__|  
                                  \/               \/             \/     \/       " + version);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ccolor1;
                    data01 = new byte[20];
                    data03 = new byte[100];
                    data04 = new byte[100];
                    Console.Write(" Enter IPv4 address of server : ");
                    ip01 = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write(" Enter port to connect on : ");
                    port01 = Console.ReadLine();
                    ipe01 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip01), Convert.ToInt32(port01));
                    tcp01 = new TcpClient();
                    Console.WriteLine(" Connecting...");
                    tcp01.Connect(ipe01);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Done.");
                    tcp01.Client.Receive(data04, SocketFlags.None);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Server message : " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data04));
                    tcp01.Client.Receive(data03, SocketFlags.None);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                    Console.WriteLine(" File on server : " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data03));
                    tcp01.Client.Receive(data01, SocketFlags.None);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                    str01 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data01);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(" file size : " + str01);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.Write(" Enter the number you see above : ");
                    length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    bytestoreceive = length;
                    Console.Write(" Save file as : ");
                    path01 = Console.ReadLine();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 60000; i++)
                    {
                        if (length % i == 0) { int02 = i; }
                    }
                    if (length < 60000) { int02 = length; }
                    int03 = length / int02;
                    s01 = File.OpenWrite(@path01);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Receiving file from " + tcp01.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + "...");
                    tcp01.Client.Send(new byte[1], SocketFlags.None);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    while (bytestoreceive > 0)
                    {
                        bw1 = new BackgroundWorker();
                        bw1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw1_DoWork);
                        bw1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw1_RunWorkerCompleted);
                        bool1 = false;
                        numbytesreceived = 0;
                        data02 = new byte[int02];
                        bw1.RunWorkerAsync();
                        while (numbytesreceived == 0) { }
                        while (numbytesreceived < int02)
                        {
                            bw1 = new BackgroundWorker();
                            bw1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw1_DoWork);
                            bw1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw1_RunWorkerCompleted);
                            bool1 = true;
                            partloop += 1;
                            int04 = int02 - numbytesreceived;
                            tcp01.Client.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("2"), 0, 1, SocketFlags.None);
                            int05 = 0;
                            data05 = new byte[int04];
                            if (int04 >= 1 && int04 <= 9) { s1 = int04 + "xxxx"; }
                            if (int04 >= 10 && int04 <= 99) { s1 = int04 + "xxx"; }
                            if (int04 >= 100 && int04 <= 999) { s1 = int04 + "xx"; }
                            if (int04 >= 1000 && int04 <= 9999) { s1 = int04 + "x"; }
                            if (int04 > 10000 && int04 <= 60000) { s1 = int04.ToString(); }
                            tcp01.Client.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s1), 0, 5, SocketFlags.None);
                            bw1.RunWorkerAsync();
                            while (int05 == 0) { }
                            if (int05 == 0) { throw new Exception("ex1"); }
                            numbytesreceived += int05;
                            bytestoreceive -= numbytesreceived;
                            s01.Write(data05, 0, data05.Length);
                            Console.WriteLine(" Received " + (length - bytestoreceive) + " / " + length + " bytes | P.B.R. loops: " + partloop.ToString());
                            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
                        }

                        if (bool1 == false)
                        {

                            bytestoreceive -= numbytesreceived;
                            s01.Write(data02, 0, int02);
                            tcp01.Client.Send(new byte[1], 0, 1, SocketFlags.None);
                            Console.WriteLine(" Received " + (length - bytestoreceive) + " / " + length + " bytes | P.B.R. loops: " + partloop.ToString());
                            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
                        }
                    }
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop + 1);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    s01.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine(" Received all data.");
                    Console.WriteLine(" Press enter to disconnect...");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    tcp01.Client.Send(new byte[1], SocketFlags.None);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Disconnecting...");
                    tcp01.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine(" Done.");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Error! : " + e.Message.ToString() + " - " + e.Data.ToString() + " - " + e.TargetSite.ToString());
                    if (!(tcp01 == null)) { tcp01.Close(); }
                    if (!(s01 == null)) { s01.Close(); }
                    Console.Write(" Press enter to continue..."); Console.ReadLine();
                    newvoid();
                }
            }
        }

        static void bw1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                bw1.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Error! : " + e1.Message.ToString() + " - " + e1.Data.ToString() + " - " + e1.TargetSite.ToString());
                if (!(tcp01 == null)) { tcp01.Close(); }
                if (!(s01 == null)) { s01.Close(); }
                Console.Write(" Press enter to continue..."); Console.ReadLine();
                newvoid();
            }
        }

        static void bw1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (bool1 == false)
                {
                    numbytesreceived = tcp01.Client.Receive(data02, 0, int02, SocketFlags.None);
                }
                if (bool1 == true)
                {
                    int05 = tcp01.Client.Receive(data05, 0, int04, SocketFlags.None);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Error! : " + e2.Message.ToString() + " - " + e2.Data.ToString() + " - " + e2.TargetSite.ToString());
                if (!(tcp01 == null)) { tcp01.Close(); }
                if (!(s01 == null)) { s01.Close(); }
                Console.Write(" Press enter to continue..."); Console.ReadLine();
                newvoid();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace PortalServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static int bytesresent;
        static BackgroundWorker bw1;
        static int int06;
        static int int05;
        static string string01;
        static int bytesCreceived;
        static byte[] data06;
        static byte[] data07;
        static byte[] data08;
        static int bytessent;
        static bool bool1;
        static int bytestosend;
        static long length;
        static int int03;
        static int int02;
        static TcpListener tcp01;
        static TcpClient tcp02;
        static FileStream s01;
        static byte[] data01;
        static byte[] data03;
        static byte[] data04;
        static byte[] data05;
        static string str01;
        static string str02;
        static IPEndPoint ipe01;
        static string port01;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            newvoid();
        }
        static void newvoid()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WindowWidth = 95;
                    string version = "V:1.1.4";
                    Console.Title = (" Portal Server " + version);
                    ConsoleColor ccolor1 = new ConsoleColor();
                    ccolor1 = Console.ForegroundColor;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(@"
 __________              __         .__      _________                                
 \______   \____________/  |______  |  |    /   _____/ ______________  __ ___________ 
  |     ___/  _ \_  __ \   __\__  \ |  |    \_____  \_/ __ \_  __ \  \/ // __ \_  __ \
  |    |  (  <_> )  | \/|  |  / __ \|  |__  /        \  ___/|  | \/\   /\  ___/|  | \/
  |____|   \____/|__|   |__| (____  /____/ /_______  /\___  >__|    \_/  \___  >__|   
                                  \/               \/     \/                 \/       " + version);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ccolor1;
                    Console.Write(" Enter port for connecting clients : ");
                    port01 = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write(" Enter path of file to send : ");
                    str01 = Console.ReadLine();
                    ipe01 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Convert.ToInt32(port01));
                    tcp01 = new TcpListener(ipe01);
                    Console.Write(" Enter server message : ");
                    str02 = Console.ReadLine();
                    s01 = File.OpenRead(@str01);
                    length = s01.Length;
                    bytestosend = (int)length;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 60000; i++)
                    {
                        if (length % i == 0) { int02 = i; }
                    }
                    if (length < 60000) { int02 = (int)length; }

                    int03 = (int)length / int02;
                    tcp01.Start();
                    Console.WriteLine(" Server started. Waiting for clients...");
                    tcp02 = tcp01.AcceptTcpClient();
                    Console.WriteLine(" Client " + tcp02.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + " connected.");
                    data05 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str02);
                    tcp02.Client.Send(data05, SocketFlags.None);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    data04 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str01);
                    tcp02.Client.Send(data04, SocketFlags.None);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    data03 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(length.ToString());
                    tcp02.Client.Send(data03, SocketFlags.None);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Waiting for response...");
                    tcp02.Client.Receive(new byte[1], SocketFlags.None);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Received response...");
                    Console.WriteLine(" Sending file to " + tcp02.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + "...");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                    while (bytestosend > 0)
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
                        bool1 = false;
                        bytessent = 0;
                        bw1 = new BackgroundWorker();
                        bw1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw1_DoWork);
                        bw1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw1_RunWorkerCompleted);
                        data01 = new byte[int02];
                        s01.Read(data01, 0, data01.Length);
                        bw1.RunWorkerAsync();
                        while (bytessent == 0) { }
                        if (bytessent != int02) { throw new Exception("unable to write bytes, insufficient memory."); }
                        while (true)
                        {
                            data07 = new byte[1];
                            tcp02.Client.Receive(data07, 0, 1, SocketFlags.None);
                            if (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data07) == "2")
                            {
                                bytesresent = 0;
                                bool1 = true;
                                bw1 = new BackgroundWorker();
                                bw1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw1_DoWork);
                                bw1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw1_RunWorkerCompleted);
                                data06 = new byte[5];
                                bytesCreceived = tcp02.Client.Receive(data06, 0, 5, SocketFlags.None);
                                if (bytesCreceived != 5) { throw new Exception("invalid client response."); }
                                string01 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data06);
                                string01 = string01.Replace("x", "");
                                int05 = Convert.ToInt32(string01);
                                int06 = int02 - int05;
                                bytestosend -= int05;
                                data08 = new byte[int05];
                                Buffer.BlockCopy(data01, int06, data08, 0, int05);
                                bw1.RunWorkerAsync();
                                while (bytesresent == 0) { }
                                Console.WriteLine(" Sent " + (length - bytestosend) + " / " + length + " bytes");
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
                                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
                            }
                            if (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data07) != "2")
                            {
                                bool1 = false;
                                bytestosend -= bytessent;
                                Console.WriteLine(" Sent " + (length - bytestosend) + " / " + length + " bytes");
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop + 1);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    s01.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine(" All data sent.");
                    Console.WriteLine(" Waiting for terminate message...");
                    tcp02.Client.Receive(new byte[1], SocketFlags.None);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Received terminate message.");
                    tcp02.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine(" Stopping client and server.");
                    tcp01.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine(" Done. Press enter to continue...");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }

                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Error! : " + e.Message.ToString() + " - " + e.Data.ToString() + " - " + e.TargetSite.ToString());
                    if (!(tcp02 == null)) { tcp02.Close(); }
                    if (!(tcp01 == null)) { tcp01.Stop(); }
                    if (!(s01 == null)) { s01.Close(); }
                    Console.Write(" Press enter to continue..."); Console.ReadLine();
                    newvoid();
                }
            }
        }

        static void bw1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                bw1.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Error! : " + e1.Message.ToString() + " - " + e1.Data.ToString() + " - " + e1.TargetSite.ToString());
                if (!(tcp02 == null)) { tcp02.Close(); }
                if (!(tcp01 == null)) { tcp01.Stop(); }
                if (!(s01 == null)) { s01.Close(); }
                Console.Write(" Press enter to continue..."); Console.ReadLine();
                newvoid();
            }
        }

        static void bw1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (bool1 == false)
                {
                    bytessent = tcp02.Client.Send(data01, 0, data01.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                }
                if (bool1 == true)
                {
                    bytesresent = tcp02.Client.Send(data08, 0, data08.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Error! : " + e2.Message.ToString() + " - " + e2.Data.ToString() + " - " + e2.TargetSite.ToString());
                if (!(tcp02 == null)) { tcp02.Close(); }
                if (!(tcp01 == null)) { tcp01.Stop(); }
                Console.Write(" Press enter to continue..."); Console.ReadLine();
                if (!(s01 == null)) { s01.Close(); }
                newvoid();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen if you are not emptying the network buffer correctly at the client end and the TCP window size is reduced to zero as a consequence.

This could be happening with your use of

```
tcp01.Client.Receive(data04, SocketFlags.None);
```

which may not be clearing the buffer sufficiently, see [MSDN](http://www.networkcomms.net/how-to-create-a-client-server-application-in-minutes/). You want to call Receive continuously until no further data is available.

If you would like a working example as a comparison please see [here](http://www.networkcomms.net/how-to-create-a-client-server-application-in-minutes/).

Comment: i used the Array.Clear() method and then the garbage collector, still having the same results.

Comment: Array.Clear() on the buffer you provide to the Receive method? i.e. data04 in my example? If so that is not the buffer I meant. The network buffer is what is copied into data04, if you do not call the receive method sufficient times then you still have data getting left in the network buffer, potentially causing your problem. This is only my best guess.

Comment: how might i go about clearing the network buffer without terminating the ongoing connection?

Comment: i tried putting my heavy lifting send and receive methods on a new thread with the system.componentmodel.backgroundworker. didnt help...

Comment: It fixed the zero window problem but unveiled a few more issues I had, the main was I needed the Socket.NoDelay option to be true on only the client. I enabled fragmentation and added a larger buffer(40k). No problems yet.

Comment: actually didnt even need the no-delay option, just a larger buffer, separate threading, and increased wait between sends.